# Выполнение службы с правами для запуска http-сервера

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service

Есть приложение, которое должно работать как Windows Сервис. Приложение должно запускать http сервер (`HttpListener`). Но запуск `HttpListener.Start()` требует прав администратора. Как запустить Службу с правами администратора?

Пытался:

- Добавил manifest-файл с правами администратора;
- В настройке инсталятора добавлял `Account`: `ServiceAccount.LocalService`, `ServiceAccount.LocalSystem`;

Ничего не помогает. Как же запустить сервис с привилегиями администратора?

Comment: Для прослушивания порта не нужны права администратора, ответ Pavel Mayorov самый правильный. У нас в процедуре установки сервиса также есть шаг netsh

Answer (score 1):

Для HttpListener требуются не права администратора - а права на прослушивание конкретного URL. Разрешить службе прослушивать указанный URL можно при помощи команды netsh:

```
netsh http add urlacl {url} user="{login}"
```

Здесь `{url}` - это прослушиваемый вашей службой префикс URL в формате [UrlPrefix](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Http/urlprefix-strings), должен совпадать с тем который вы прослушиваете или быть его предком.

`{login}` - это имя учетки, от которой работает ваша служба. Обычно это `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`, но на современных версиях Windows лучше использовать индивидуальную учётку службы `NT SERVICE\{имя службы}`.

Разумеется, команду netsh нужно запускать из командной строки, работающей от имени администратора.

Comment: Хм, я пробовал, только как login использовал логин своей учетки. Сейчас попробую как LocalService. К сожалению, доступа к созданию учеток для тестов нету...

Comment: @Саня вам не надо **создавать** учётку! Вам нужно дать права той учётке, от которой уже настроен запуск службы. Используемые по умолчанию учётки я вам назвал в ответе.

Comment: @Саня и да, у локального администратора всегда есть возможность заводить новые учётки

Answer (score 0):

Служба, как правило, предварительно устанавливается => можно указать под какой учеткой ей работать.

Службы=>нажимаем на нашу службу правой кнопкой=>свойства=>Вход в систему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вводим учетные данные и радуемся.

Comment: пробовал вводить учетку (она доменная), служба успешно устанавливается, но отказывается запускаться. Можно ли как то отслелить неуспех запуска службы?

Comment: А ошибки какие пишет? Этот способ должен работать. Может быть в службе самой косяк?

Comment: сейчас, переустановлю и скажу какая точно ошибка. По идее у меня OnStart и OnStop в try/catch завернуты, и по логам все сухо. Если без учетки стартануть, соответственно в логе будет падение службы с ошибкой прав.

Comment: Лучше все-таки запускать не от имени реального пользователя, а от служебного. Потому что пользователя могут отключить, или он может сменить пароль...

Comment: @iluxa1810, Не удалось запустить службу Service-name на Локальный компьютер. Ошибка 1053: Служба не ответила на запрос своевременное.

Comment: @Саня, а у вас там в методе запуска нету чего-то брутального? Служба должна за 30 сек запустится и вернуть управление.

Comment: @Саня, в OnStart должен создаваться Thread/Task с конкретной логикой работы службы и возвращаться управление. Если управление не возвращается, то вылетает сообщение с ошибкой.

Comment: @iluxa1810, мне стыдно.. голову запудрил и забыл вынести слушатели HttpListener'a в потоки... вопрос решен, спасибо за вправление рук! :D